# Use jQuery to group JSON data coming from Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, jquery-ui

I have the following array, which is extracted to from MySQL database using PDO.

```
[{
      "tbl":"1",
      "orid":"915",
      "date":"2021-12-30 12:46:48",
      "flag":0
   },
   {
      "tbl":"2",
      "orid":"914",
      "date":"2021-12-30 12:46:21",
      "flag":0
   },
   {
      "tbl":"3",
      "orid":"913",
      "date":"2021-12-30 12:45:00",
      "flag":0
   },
   {
      "tbl":"1",
      "orid":"911",
      "date":"2021-12-30 12:27:17",
      "flag":1
   }]
```

I am trying to retrieve this data via Ajax and build/attach div's accordingly. It doesn't work as I am failing at even displaying the data parameters and keys. This is the success(data) function:

```
$.each(data,function(i,j){
    content ='<span>'+j[i]+'<br /></span>';
    $('.timeline').append(content);
    });
```

I want to place the data in the following format:

```
<div tbl="1">
<span class="header">Ref 1</span>
<div orid="915" class="order">...</div>
<div orid="911" class="order">...</div>
</div>
<div tbl="2">
<span class="header">Ref 2</span>
<div orid="914" class="order">...</div>
</div>
<div tbl="3">
<span class="header">Ref 3</span>
<div orid="913" class="order">...</div>
</div>
```

The tricky part is to attach each order/orid to an existing tbl div or create a new tbl div if it doesn't exist yet because of recurring ajax calls (each time loading 10 rows).

Comment: There's no `tbl` or `orid` attribute in HTML4/5. Use a `data-*` attribute instead.

Comment: The `success` handler doesn't even try to find one of those "tables". And what is `.timeline`? -> What have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Comment: This has nothing to do with `json` nor `jquery-ui`

Comment: I do not see the AJAX code to call the data. I do not see what steps you have tried. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  var resultData = [{
      "tbl": "1",
      "orid": "915",
      "date": "2021-12-30 12:46:48",
      "flag": 0
    },
    {
      "tbl": "2",
      "orid": "914",
      "date": "2021-12-30 12:46:21",
      "flag": 0
    },
    {
      "tbl": "3",
      "orid": "913",
      "date": "2021-12-30 12:45:00",
      "flag": 0
    },
    {
      "tbl": "1",
      "orid": "911",
      "date": "2021-12-30 12:27:17",
      "flag": 1
    }
  ];

  function makeNewTable(tableData, target) {
    if (tableData == undefined || target == undefined) {
      return false;
    }
    var tableId = tableData.tbl;
    var table = $("<div>", {
      id: "table-" + tableId,
      class: "table"
    }).appendTo(target);
    $("<div>", {
      class: "header"
    }).html("Ref " + tableId).appendTo(table);
    $("<div>", {
      class: "order"
    }).data("orid", tableData.orid).html(tableData.date).appendTo(table);
    $("<input>", {
      type: "checkbox",
    }).prop({
      checked: tableData.flag == 1 ? true : false,
      disabled: true
    }).appendTo(table);
  };

  function updateTable(newData, target) {
    if (newData == undefined || target == undefined) {
      return false;
    }
    $("<div>", {
      class: "order"
    }).data("orid", newData.orid).html(newData.date).appendTo(target);
    $("<input>", {
      type: "checkbox",
    }).prop({
      checked: newData.flag == 1 ? true : false,
      disabled: true
    }).appendTo(target);
  }

  function showData(data, target) {
    if (data == undefined || target == undefined) {
      return false;
    }
    var tbl;
    $.each(data, function(index, row) {
      if ($("#table-" + row.tbl).length == 0) {
        makeNewTable(row, $("#results-table"));
      } else {
        updateTable(row, $("#table-" + row.tbl));
      }
    });
  }

  showData(resultData, $("#results-table"));
});
```

```css
.header {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0.2em 0.4em;
}

.order {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.2em 0.4em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="results-table">
</div>
```

You can see here how it might be easier to break up the different scenarios with Functions. This way you can make a new Table or update an existing table as needed.

**Update**

You may consider using DataTables. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/u6bdcsqz/51/

Primary Code:

```
function makeTable(keys, data, parent) {
    var table = $("<table>").appendTo(parent);
    $("<thead>").appendTo(table);
    $("<tr>").appendTo($("thead", table));
    $.each(keys, function(i, k) {
      $("<th>").html(k).appendTo($("thead tr", table));
    });
    $("<tbody>").appendTo(table);
    var row;
    $.each(data, function(i, r) {
      row = $("<tr>").appendTo($("tbody", table));
      $("<td>").html("Table " + r.tbl).appendTo(row);
      $("<td>", {
        class: "order"
      }).html(r.orid).appendTo(row);
      $("<td>", {
        class: "date"
      }).html(r.date).appendTo(row);
      $("<td>", {
        class: "flag"
      }).html(r.flag == 1 ? "X" : "&nbsp;").appendTo(row);
    });
    var groupColumn = 0;
    dataTable = table.DataTable({
      "paging": false,
      "columnDefs": [{
        "visible": false,
        "targets": groupColumn
      }],
      "order": [
        [groupColumn, 'asc']
      ],
      "drawCallback": function(settings) {
        var api = this.api();
        var rows = api.rows({
          page: 'current'
        }).nodes();
        var last = null;

        api.column(groupColumn, {
          page: 'current'
        }).data().each(function(group, i) {
          if (last !== group) {
            $(rows).eq(i).before(
              '<tr class="group"><td colspan="3">' + group + '</td></tr>'
            );
            last = group;
          }
        });
      }
    });
    table.on('click', 'tr.group', function() {
      var currentOrder = table.order()[0];
      if (currentOrder[0] === groupColumn && currentOrder[1] === 'asc') {
        table.order([groupColumn, 'desc']).draw();
      } else {
        table.order([groupColumn, 'asc']).draw();
      }
    });
    console.log("Table created, " + data.length + " rows.");
  }

  function updateTable(data) {
    $.each(data, function(i, r) {
      dataTable.row.add(["Table " + r.tbl, r.orid, r.date, r.flag]).draw(false);
    });
    console.log("Table updated, added " + data.length + " rows.");
  }

  function showData(tableData, target) {
    if (tableData == undefined || target == undefined) {
      return false;
    }
    if ($("table", target).length > 0) {
      console.log("Table Found, updating");
      updateTable(tableData, $("table", target));
    } else {
      console.log("No Table, creating.");
      makeTable(["Table", "Order", "Date", "Flag"], tableData, target);
    }
  }
```

It's more than you may want yet it give you all the features you are asking about.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to order it by orid or date desc? Also considering new data (which calls the same function) which should be attached to the top as well as move the Reference group element to the top. Imagine new item comes in via websocket and it's assigned to Ref3. Then Ref3 should move to top and be placed above the existing row.

Comment: I tried to replicate here https://jsfiddle.net/p6wbkmd8/1/

Comment: @jq1080 I would advise creating an actual Table then and applying DataTables so that you get search filter and ordering built in.

Comment: For example: https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/row_grouping.html

Comment: I found, but it might be an overkill. I am still trying with your codebase. https://jsfiddle.net/2ys0bhc6/

Comment: Take a look: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/u6bdcsqz/51/

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example by your sample data, instead of `tbl, orid` I've used `data-tbl` and `data-orid` attributes.

```js
const data = [{
    "tbl": "1",
    "orid": "915",
    "date": "2021-12-30 12:46:48",
    "flag": 0
  },
  {
    "tbl": "2",
    "orid": "914",
    "date": "2021-12-30 12:46:21",
    "flag": 0
  },
  {
    "tbl": "3",
    "orid": "913",
    "date": "2021-12-30 12:45:00",
    "flag": 0
  },
  {
    "tbl": "1",
    "orid": "911",
    "date": "2021-12-30 12:27:17",
    "flag": 1
  }
]


$.each(data, function(i, data) {
  let target = $(`div[data-tbl=${data.tbl}]`)
  if (target.length == 0) {
    target = $(`<div data-tbl="${data.tbl}"><span class="header">Ref ${data.tbl}</span></div>`);
    $('.timeline').append(target)
  }
  const content = `<div data-orid="${data.orid}" class="order">${data.orid}</div>`;
  target.append(content);
});
```

```css
.header{
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="timeline"></div>
```

Comment: Works fine in the snippet, but I cannot replicate it on my own website for some reason.

Comment: what is the problem? can I help to solve?

Comment: I think it's the order of code. .timeline is not constructed yet when the code already runs. Also the JSON code coming from ajax is identical you have in the const data but for some reason is not working

Comment: you can put your code in `$(document).ready(function(){ //code })` to be sure that `.timeline` has constructed when you receive data. also you can check the browser's console to see if there is an error.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I figured it out - i had to use JSON.parse(data). I have another problem. If I add a header span element to display the flag name to the group tbl div then it's only added at the bottom. Please see my edited post

Comment: You're welcome, I edited my response to add `span.header`.

Comment: This works great. I have additional problem. I added if check for target.append(content) to switch to target.prepend(content) when the new item is coming from a websocket connection. The new entry is however added above the <span header>

Comment: Also the sorting should be orderid or date descending. Meaning if new rows come in, both the ref element and the row itself move to the top. Example here: https://jsfiddle.net/heqcva8z/5/